# constant function is continuous

Tags: general-topology

I need to show, that when we have $X,Y$ - any metric spaces and 

$f:X \ni x \to a \in Y$ is constant , then $f$ is continuous .

$(X,\tau_{1}),(Y,\tau_{2})   $ - topological spaces : $f: X\to Y$. 
I know a definition : $f: X\to Y $ is continuous if $ \forall_{W \in \tau_{2}}\  f^{-1}[W] \in \tau_{1} $ .

Maybe let $U$ be open in Y , then id$x^{-1}(U) = U$
$const^{-1}(U)= \begin{cases}
x , a\in U \\
\emptyset , a \notin U
\end{cases}$
?

Comment: What does constantly mean?

Comment: Constant function

Comment: so for any open set in $Y$ the preimage under $f$ is either empty or the whole space. Are those sets open in $X$?

Comment: I think  yes   , they are .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This holds for every topological space, not just for metric spaces. Let $a \in Y$ be fixed. Since

$$f:X \to Y, x \mapsto a$$ holds, the preimage of any $V \subseteq Y$ is

- $\emptyset$, iff $a \notin V$,
- whole $X$, iff $a \in V$, like you already denoted.

Thus the preimage of ANY subset of $Y$ is either $\emptyset$ or whole $X$.
Clearly $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open in $X$ by definition of a topology, thus the preimage of any subset of $Y$ ,especially the open ones, is open in $X$. Thus $f$ is continuous as by definition a map between topological spaces is continuous if and only if it pulls back open sets onto open sets, thus $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for $V \subseteq Y$ open in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let U be an open set of y.
Case one.  If a in U, what is the image of U?
Case two.  If a not in U, what is the image of U?

Do not guess but use the definition of inverse image to caculate the inverse image of a set by a function.  Also look up the fact that a function is continuous iff for every open subset of the codomain, the inverse image is open.  Enjoy the workout.